# How to invoke python script from Robotframework as part of Teardown

Tags: python-3.x, windows, selenium-webdriver, scripting, robotframework

I wanted to run python script as part of teardown in Robotframework. But it throws error "System cannot find the file specified"

In my Testcase.txt, I have

*** Settings ***

Library           Process

Test Teardown     SystemCleanup

In my Resource folder, where the keyword is present

*** Settings ***

Library           Process

SystemCleanup

```
  Run Process       python C:\\Testcases\\Cleanup_script.py arg1 arg2
```

I am running the robot command from Testcases folder and I am getting the error

**Teardown failed:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified**

NOTE:
1 tried giving relative path, full path of the script but not able to succeed

Comment: Did you try space separate? Something like `Run Process    python    C:\\Testcases\\Cleanup_script.py    arg1    arg2` If issue persists it could be good add log from Run Process stdout and stderr into the question. `${result}=    Run Process    python    C:\\Testcases\\Cleanup_script.py    arg1    arg2` `Log    Stdout ${result.stdout}    console=True` `Log    Stderr ${result.stderr}    console=True`. Stdout or stderr could give a hint.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the Testcases folder, is there any reason why you need to invoke "Run Process" command for a python file in the same folder? My suggestion would be to attach that python file as Library and directly invoke it from the Robot file.

Foe example, lets say this is how your Cleanup_script.py looks like:

```
#Cleanup_script.py

def cleanup_system(self):
    # do cleanup
```

This is how you can modify your Robot file:

```
# Testcases.robot

*** Settings ***

Library | Process

Library | Cleanup_script.py

Test Teardown | SystemCleanup

*** Keywords ***

SystemCleanup
    Cleanup System
```

This should invoke the clean up function from your py file.